# Why does eclipse require multiple imports?

Tags: java, eclipse

a.java has import java.io.*; I dragged all the java to link to the project, but some ended up with red icon, while a.java with yellow. Those with red don't have imports, and act like there are no imports, but that's why I put a.java there. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: could you please rephrase your question

Comment: Go to the Markers panel and investigate all the error messages.  The reason might be something you didn't think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because `A.java` has `import java.io.*;` it doesn't mean that `B.java` has access to `java.io.*;`. `B.java` will have to import what it wants to use explicitly, even if they are in the same package. 
This is specified in [§6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) and [§7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) of the JLS.

From section 6.3:

> An import declaration makes types or members available by their simple names only within the compilation unit that actually contains the import declaration. The scope of the type(s) or member(s) introduced by an import declaration specifically does not include the PackageName of a package declaration, other import declarations in the current compilation unit, or other compilation units in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of an import is the .java file in which it appears. That is, importing something in a.java had no effect on b.java at all.

The "import" keyword actually has a somewhat unfortunate name. People new to Java often assume that it's somehow "pulling stuff in". All it really does is give you a shorthand for referring to something in another package. For example, you could just write "java.io.File" everywhere you want that class, rather than importing it and referring to it as "File". The compiled code ends up exactly the same whether you use imports our fully qualified names.

Comment: +1 since I think the answer is right but _definitely_ for decoding the question :-)

Comment: Why is that (scope of an import is the .java file in which it appears) so? Why not the project? What does the yellow icon mean?

Comment: put the mouse pointer over the yellow icon. A popup will give you more information about the problem. Its possibly an import that is not used by the code in the file

Comment: @user93200 because that's the way the language is defined to work in the Java Language Specification. sees for why Java was designed to work this way... it's pretty typical behavior for this sort of language feature to be scoped to the compilation unit, and in Java (like most languages) a source file is a compilation unit. #include in C is also (effectively) scoped to the source file, for example.

Comment: popup doesn't appear, but in the file on the import line it does say that import is not used by the code.